# Bounded holomorphic function in the Unit disc having essential singularity at a boundary point.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $F\in\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{D},\mathbb{D})$ and suppose $\sup\{|F(z)|:z\in\mathbb{D}\}=1
.$ Suppose there exists $R>0$ such that $F$ is holomorphic in $B(1;R)\setminus\{1\}$ and has essential singularity at $1.$ I have following questions:

1. Does the set of functions satisfying above property is nonempty?
2. Suppose the answer for the first question is positive. Is it true that for every $r,\,0<r\leq R,$ we have $F(B(1;r)\cap\mathbb{D})$ is dense in $\mathbb{D}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, for example $F(z)=\exp((z-1)^{-1})+1-e^{-1/2}$. Indeed, the function $\phi(z)=(z-1)^{-1}$ maps $\mathbb D$ onto the half-plane $\operatorname{Re}\zeta<-1/2$, which is then mapped by $\exp$ onto the disk $|w|<e^{-1/2}$.
2. No, because for $F$ given above, $F(\mathbb D)$ is a disk of radius $e^{-1/2}$ centered at $1-e^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A request to you, I asked a question titled"A version of Casorati Weierstrass Theoem". The above counterexample also works for this question. So can you post your solution there also, as it will be fair if you do that. Thanks again.